# Gibt es das Wort »buchführen«?

Tags: word-usage

Umgangssprachlich kommt mir das Wort sehr bekannt vor, allerdings kann ich im Duden nur das Wort *buchführend* finden.

Ist *buchführen* ein richtiges deutsches Wort oder nur in der Umgangssprache gebräuchlich?

Comment: Scheint's zu geben, da oben steht's ;)

Comment: Wieso soll es das nicht geben?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soweit ich weiß gibt es das Wort nicht, allerdings gibt es sehr wohl den Ausdruck *"über etwas Buch führen"*. Das Zusammenschreiben ist wohl nur im Falle der Verlaufsform zulässig.

Answer (score 3):

Unstrittig ist wohl, dass es die

> Buchführung

gibt. Gibt es aber die Buchführung, die ja nach aller Logik die Substantivierung der Tätigkeit ist, und für Tätigkeiten haben wir Verben, so ist wohl davon auszugehen, dass es auch das Verb

> buchführen

gibt.

Interessanterweise listet das Duden Universalwörterbuch (jüngste Ausgabe) nur die "Buchführung" auf, nicht "buchführen".

Doch lässt sich aus dem Umstand, dass der Duden nicht über alles und jedes Buch führt, nicht schließen, dass etwas nicht doch existiert. Onkel Duden sagt ja selbst von sich, er gehe deskriptiv vor, nicht normativ. Und man darf Verzeichnisse wie den Duden wohl als Spitze des Eisbergs ansehen: Nur die stärksten Lexeme durchbrechen die Wasseroberfläche des Ozeans sprachlicher Wirklichkeit und werden im Buch abgedruckt.

Jetzt kann man natürlich diskutieren über verschiedene Formen der Existenz, die Wörter so durchleben können.

Eine Form der Existenz wäre das mehr oder weniger häufige Vorkommen in mehr oder weniger wohlgeformten mündlichen und schriftlichen Sprachäußerungen.

Eine andere Form wäre die potentielle Existenz, also etwa: Im System der gegebenen Sprache wäre die Existenz eines solchen Lexems sinnvoll anzunehmen, auch wenn es in der Praxis (d.h. in einem gegebenen Textkorpus, das man zur Überprüfung zur Hand hat) vielleicht nicht konkret nachweisbar ist.

Für *buchführen* würde ich beide Formen der Existenz annehmen, auch wenn, wenn man sein Textkorpus auf nur den Duden beschränkt, kein Nachweis dafür zu finden ist.

Comment: Vielleicht führt der Duden *buchführen* nicht auf, weil er lieber *Buch führt?*

Comment: In _Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch,_ 7. Aufl. (2011) heißt es explizit: „Man schreibt getrennt: _Buch führen_ (nicht: _buchführen_). Das Partizip I kann dagegen getrennt oder zusammengeschrieben werden: die _Buch führende / buchführende_ Geschäftsstelle.“

Answer (score 2):

Siehe auch Duden, Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle, 8. Aufl. 2016:

> **Buch führen**: Man schreibt getrennt: Buch führen (nicht: buchführen). Das Partizip I kann dagegen getrennt oder
>   zusammengeschrieben werden: die Buch führende / buchführende
>   Geschäftsstelle.

Also: Die Phrase schreibt man "Buch führen", deshalb findest du auch "buchführen" nicht im Duden, aber im Partizip kann man zusammenschreiben.